# Access denied when sending text from RichEditBox through HttpClient POST

Tags: c#, uwp, richeditbox

I'm using `HttpClient` to POST a user created string to a server API and get the result. Previously I used a `TextBox` to allow the user to enter the string but I wanted pretty colours so I tried to replace the `TextBox` with a `RichEditBox` but failed miserably. When using the `TextBox` everything worked fine but when using the `RichEditBox` I get an "Access denied" message. I get the text from the `RichEditBox` with the `Document.GetText` method. I can get it to work by either inserting a static string in the place where I get the text or in the place where I send the string into a `FormUrlEncodedContent`. The string is edited before and after adding the text from the `RichEditBox`, and sent to another method.

**TL:DR**: Sending a string from a `TextBox` with a `HttpClient` using `POST` works but not when replacing the `TextBox` with a `RichEditBox`.

Here's the full error message:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))'

Does anyone have a solution or an explanation to why this is happening?

**Edit**

Code sample:

```
private async void RichEditBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter)
    {
        await RunCode();    //The error points to this line
    }
}

private async void RunCode()
{
    string code = CodeBefore;
    foreach (RichEditBox tb in editStack.Children)  //If I comment out the foreach loop I don't get any errors
    {
        if (tb.Tag.ToString() == "input")
        {
            tb.Document.GetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.None, out string thisLine);
            code += thisLine;
        }
    }
    code += CodeAfter;
    await RunCSharp(code);
}

private async Task<Code> RunCSharp(string code)
{
    Code re = new Code();

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("LanguageChoiceWrapper", "1"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Program", code),              //If I replace code with a string  I don't get any errors
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ShowWarnings", "false")
            });

        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage msg = await client.PostAsync("http://mywebaddress.com/run", content);
            re = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Code>(await msg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
        catch { }
    }

    return re;
}
```

Comment: Can you attach some sample code to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @VijayNirmal Thanks for the quick response! I've done as you asked and added all the code I believe is relevant

Comment: Since you are using `RichEditBox` to get the text, every line in the `RichEditBox` will end with `\r`. So replace the `\r` with `""`(empty string) before using it

Comment: @VijayNirmal Again, thanks for the answer :-) You were right, I had a bunch of `\r` in the string, but removing the didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Check for any other unwanted string or escape string and remove it

Comment: @VijayNirmal I made a test to see the difference between the string from the `TextBox` and the `RichEditBox` but `richEditBoxString.Replace("\r", "") == textBoxString` returns `true`. Is there any characters that would seem the same that aren't in reality?

Comment: Keep a breakpoint in `new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Program", code)` line and check the value of the string.

Comment: @VijayNirmal This is what I get: `Program=using+System%3Busing+System.Collections.Generic%3Busing+System.Linq%3Busing+System.Text.RegularExpressions%3Bnamespace+Rextester%7Bpublic+class+Program%7Bpublic+static+void+Main%28string%5B%5D+args%29%7BConsole.WriteLine%28%22Hello+World%21%22%29%3B%7D%7D%7D`. And when I do it with a `TextBox` I get the exact same.

Comment: One last test, Use `TextBox`, Keep a breakpoint in `new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Program", code)` line and change the value of the `code` string when the compiler reaches the breakpoint to the string which you got it using `RichEditBox`. Testing this way will tell us whether the string is the problem or something else.